Majorization and second largest probability
I have a vector $p_1\geq p_2\geq\cdots p_m\geq0$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^mp_i=1$. Majorization is defined as follows: For vectors $ x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n $, $ x \prec y $ if $\sum_{i=1}^k x_{[i]} \leq \sum_{i=1}^k y_{[i]}, \quad k = 1, \ldots, n-1$
with equality when $ k = n$, where $x_{[1]}\geq\cdots\geq x_{[m]}$.
Given the definition of majorization and a constant $q$, can I express the condition $ p_{2} \geq q $ using an equivalent majorization inequality where $r\prec p$, such that the vector $r $ depends only on $ q$ and $ m$.
I tried $r=(q,q,\frac{1-2q}{m-2},\cdots,\frac{1-2q}{m-2})$, but it didn't work. To relax the problem a bit, the equivalence can exist only for a certain range of $q$ (like $q<\frac{1}{m}$).
Thanks in advance for any help.

If $r$ depends only on $q\neq0$ and $m$, then the vector $e_1 := (1,0,0,\ldots,0)$ will always satisfy $r \prec e_1$, but will not have its second coordinate $\ge q$.
